# PyCharm inspections - mysql query with replaceable parameters

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I found this a hard thing to google and get relevant results.

Is there a way to prevent PyCharm complaining "unable to resolve column 's' " without turning off the entire inspection? I know I can turn the inspection off for a line but doing it for every line would defeat the value of the inspection.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = %s"
```

I have set the SQL dialect. I suspect it just isn't possible - next step, contact jetbrains.

Replaceable parameters are such a key concept and the PyCharm sanity checking of column names is really valuable, it'll be a shame if there isn't a way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm, these inserted parameters are called 'User Parameters'. You can make PyCharm aware of them in Settings | Tools | Database | User Parameters. Then make sure "Enable in string literals with SQL injection" is checked.

In the rest of the window you can see the various notations of SQL Parameters that PyCharm will then detect. '%s' is in there by default, so after clicking the checkbox everything should work well.